# How to return the json format of a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask

I have a dataframe `df` and I tried converting dataframe to json as below:

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/graph')
def plot():
    df=pd.DataFrame([['madrid', 10], ['venice', 20], ['las vegas', 40], ['brighton', 35]],
                      columns=['city', 'temp'])
    jsondata=df.to_json(orient='records')
    return jsondata

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

o/p as follows:

```
[{"city":"madrid","temp":10},{"city":"venice","temp":20},{"city":"las vegas","temp":40},{"city":"brighton","temp":35}]
```

and if I use `orient='split'` o/p is :

```
{"columns":["city","temp"],"index":[0,1,2,3],"data":[["madrid",10],["venice",20],["las vegas",40],["brighton",35]]}
```

I am looking for an output as:

```
{
"trace1":[{"city":["madrid",....],"temp":[10,20,...]}]
}
```

No idea to get for `city` and `temp` as above ,but tried for `trace1` atleast as `return {"trace1":jsondata}` but this is giving me

```
{
    "trace1": "{\"columns\":[\"city\",\"temp\"],\"index\":[0,1,2,3],\"data\":[[\"madrid\",10],[\"venice\",20],[\"las vegas\",40],[\"brighton\",35]]}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='list'` for dictionary and then convert to json:

```
import json

jsondata= json.dumps({"trace1":[df.to_dict(orient='list')]})
print (jsondata)

{"trace1": [{"city": ["madrid", "venice", "las vegas", "brighton"],"temp": [10, 20, 40, 35]}]}
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for ...thanks jez

Comment: so couldn't we use df.to_json to achieve the same ??

Comment: @Codenewbie - it is not implemented, test `df.to_json(orient='list')`

Comment: ValueError: Invalid value 'list' for option 'orient'

Comment: also may i know why the slashes appear when i tried `return {"trace1":jsondata}`?

Comment: @Codenewbie - I think there is double convert values to json, so second parsed json add `\` for escape.

Comment: Should be `orient='records'`.